# How could Ant-Man be seen?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In *Ant-Man*, before the main heist is set to occur, Scott needs to break into an old Stark warehouse to steal a signal disruptor.

> When he gets there, he realises that the old Stark warehouse is now the base of The Avengers, and he ends up getting into a fight with The Falcon.

How can this character even see Ant-Man in order to fight him?

Comment: He has special glasses. Also he isn't ant sized, he's slightly bigger so you could focus on movement and see him (like when he is running on a shoulder of some bodyguard).

Comment: @Zikato He is smaller than the biggest ants we see, and the character in question first spots him when he is standing on a roof, not running. What special glasses?

Comment: When there were scene in Falcon POV, you could see that his glasses target the Ant-man. Also he went to the roof because alarm was triggered and then he saw him with the glasses.

Comment: @Zikato Do we see the glasses highlight Ant Man, or point him out? If so, put it as an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's roughly the same size, or smaller than Antony.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Yes; there's a little targeting reticle that moves around automatically trying to lock onto Ant-Man's signature.

Comment: This was obvious from the scene itself. We see his Glass zoom in and track Lang... No big mystery here.

Comment: Someone (@DrRDizzle) just saw Ant-Man!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I found out that Ant-Man is hyphenated and went back to edit all my *Ant-Man* questions and answers, forgetting that they would be bumped becuase of it. I done goofed.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: naw hyphens should be correct, you did the right thing. Ant-Man is indeed hyphenated, as is Spider-Man, but not Iron Man. Where’s the consistency? Anyone would think that in the 60s everyone was on drugs the whole time or something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This character can see Ant-man because of the special glasses he wears.
 When we get to see the Point of View of this character, it highlights the Ant-Man and there is red circle / rectangular around him.

Comment: also note at the bottom of Falcon's POV it says something like "Mode: Zoom"

Comment: Given that Falcon is usually flying high, it makes sense that he can zoom in enough to see details on the ground from up there.  Seeing an ant-sized human while standing on the ground isn't fundamentally different from seeing humans that look as small as ants from way up in the sky.

Comment: Also Ant-Man is small, not invisible. When an ant carries a bit of a leaf, you can see the bit of the leaf, even though it’s smaller than the ant.

Answer (score 18):

The basic answer has already been given by Zikato: Falcon has goggles as part of his suit that apparently include enhanced targeting protocols and an advanced Heads Up Display (HUD).

Promotional image of Falcon showing goggles as a part of his suit while he confronts Ant-Man before Ant-Man shrinks:

[image: Promotional image of Falcon showing goggles as a part of his suit while he confronts Ant-Man before Ant-Man shrinks]

Here is a screenshot showing Falcon's POV while trying to locate Ant-Man's signature on the roof of the Avengers warehouse.

[image: Falcon's POV while trying to locate Ant-Man's signature on the roof of the Avengers warehouse]

And here's Falcon's POV while his goggles have located and locked on to Ant-Man's signature, and zoomed in to provide a better image (Ant-Man is pictured running, roughly in the center of the "zoomed" window in the HUD):

[image: Falcon's POV while his goggles have located and locked on to Ant-Man's signature, and zoomed in to provide a better image (Ant-Man is pictured running, roughly in the center of the "zoomed" window in the HUD]

And

> once Ant-Man has destroyed Falcon's suit from the inside,

you can see he's no longer able to track Ant-Man via his Falcon Goggle HUD:

[image: Falcon is no longer able to track Ant-Man via his Falcon Goggle HUD.]

Comment: Repeating the text that appears before the image adds no value whatsoever.  The alt text gives you an opportunity to describe things that are obvious to a viewer, but not otherwise conveyed in the text.  "You can see he's no longer able to track Ant-Man"  How?  How can we see that if we can't see the image?  Your "alt text" is not helpful.  You might try listening to descriptive audio sometime; it would say something like "Falcon's HUD jitters and blurs, the overlay becomes unreadable.  The telescopic view of Ant-Man is lost." _That_ is what your alt text should be, not repeating the text.

Comment: @DavidW That's not true. The alt text is for assistive technology. Previously there was no alt text. My intention when writing the answer was to share the information I wrote with readers, so that is the information that I think assistive tech users should also receive. As for the specific example of "you can see [...]", somewhat ironically, you should check again and find that the phrase "you can see" is not present in the alt text.

Comment: Personally, I feel like both kind of alt texts are fine, although I don't know if it was worth discarding one for another though. In a very context specific, the one you edited in later on is straight to the point and specifically tailored to the answer. On the other hand, the ones @DavidW initially added are more detailed, which can be nice outside of the context of the answer. I think I would have tried to mix a bit of both (relevant information to the answer, and then more detailed information which are relevant to the pictures but not directly related to the answer).